# price filter in layered navigation to show only in-stock product count

Tags: magento-1.9, price, layered-navigation

My need is to show in-stock product count only in price filters on layered nav. Is there any possible solution for this?

Currently out of stock products are visible in frontend and price filter show total count of in stock and out of stock products.

I have tried editing `catalog/product/model/layer/price.php` file. But it doesn't provide me the proper solution. If any body met with this requirement before or anyone knows what to do, please help. Thanks.

Comment: could anybody help me regarding this?